# Replace all results of "grep string" with another string

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have use this command `grep -rnw . -e "Windows"` and I would like to replace all "Windows" with "Linux". What command do I need to pipe along with the grep command? sed? xargs? I tried multiple combinations but it seems to fail.

Appreciate your help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `-l` option in `grep` and pipe to `xargs + sed`

Comment: Show us your tries

Comment: You would not use that grep command at all. `grep` is a tool to Globally match a Regular Expression and Print the result, it'd not a tool to find files or replace text in files. To Find files use `find` and to replace text in a file use `sed` or `awk`.